# What function do the "networks" and "protocol" files provide?

Tags: windows, networking

In a Windows system (in this case Windows 7) we have the "hosts" file in Windows\System32\drivers\etc

This location also has 3 other files:

1. networks
2. protocol
3. services

**Note:** the "services" file was explained in [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/402715/what-is-the-windows-drivers-etc-services-file-for). But what function does the "networks" and "protocol" files provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are used to support functions in the networking libraries:

- protocol is used by [getprotobyname](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- network is used by applications doing loopback connections.

Further reading

- [Issue 2215:     windows net: replacement for /etc/protocols](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2215)
- [networks file](http://www.thenetworkencyclopedia.com/entry/networks-file/)
- [networks(5)](http://man.netbsd.org/6.0/usr/share/man/html5/networks.html)
- [practical usage of /etc/networks file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196830/practical-usage-of-etc-networks-file)
- [Protocol Numbers](https://books.google.com/books?id=6hlNFc7drzEC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22/etc/protocol%22%20%20windows&source=bl&ots=NQXYKs3AoA&sig=hbdcWtkK3oRcPDhXbuPO0V_REiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYlfDjl7PJAhVL6iYKHc29A8IQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=%22%2Fetc%2Fprotocol%22%20%20windows&f=false) in *Windows NT TCP/IP Network Administration*
- [What would be the “lo” interface equivalent on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328908/what-would-be-the-lo-interface-equivalent-on-windows)

Comment: I am surprised that this has survived.  It's just a bunch of links and answers nothing.

Comment: Link only answers are not quality answers, unfortunately.